# How to push code to a GitHub Repo using Code Sandbox for iOS (2022)

Tags: github, codesandbox

I had trouble (even called support) and they could not answer correctly as to how to push code from CodeSandBox (iOS version) to a GitHub Remote Repo. I keep getting failed to connect (even using SSH and/either regular authentication). (They did lead me down part of the path)

Answer (score 0):

The way that I finally got it to work:
Essentially you have to use SSH (not HTTPS - this will not work!!!! on iOS)
On GitHub
First create your repo on Github (private or public), I selected to create a private one
copy the SSH name address
git@github.com:yourusername/yourprojectname.git

In CodeSandbox,
Add your repo name in the git settings from above
In the SSH Settings, hit the magic wand at the top and let it generate the public and private for you (this was the key....), do not generate a key on your own at your command line (IT WILL NOT WORK)
In the private key passphrase (leave this blank)
Change your branch in the settings to "main" as you GitHub Repo points to

Back in GitHub
Go to your Repo, go to the settings for your repo (not on your account)
Go to Deploy Keys
Add a Deploy Key, paste in the public ssh-rsa key from your code sandbox (that you let it generate), Make sure you check the box "Allow Write Access)

Then you can now commit and push to your remote repository (Took me three days of troubleshooting to figure this out) -:)